# Create React App: serve html in development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Integrating a server (say in Python or Java) with CRA can be done in two ways: "CRA first" or "Other server first"

By CRA-first I mean that the main serving component is the React server, hence serve the React application with `yarn start` and call a server api configured in `package.json`'s `proxy` setting. This is easy and clearly explained in Create React App documentation.

By "Other server first" I mean that you serve everything (HTML etc) with a web framework of your choice but that the served HTML also loads the React application. The documentation explains how to **deploy** in such situation (basically `yarn build` the app and normally load the generated JavaScript file(s) from your HTML) but not how to do this in **development**.

So, how can I serve with an arbitrary server my possibly dynamic HTML and in such HTML reference the deployment JavaScript that CRA keeps updated?

Answer (score -2):

It is explained in the documentation in the section `Static Server` https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#static-server

You just build `yarn build` and serve it using `serve -s build 4000`. Or you can use Apache/Nginx or whatever you want instead of `serve`. But you need to rebuild your application every time you make changes and restart the server. This way you won't get hot reload etc. You need Webpack server (CRA integrates it in the background) for that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In my question I put in bold "how to do this in development" meaning that if I have to wait two minutes for the "yarn build" command to finish, that wouldn't be development anymore but deployment.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. From my experience, development means on developer's computer and deployment usually means on the server.

Unfortunately if you want to real time serve static HTML without building it, it is not possible, because to get the static files, you need to build it.